# ¿Cómo puedo contar la cantidad de archivos dentro de un ZIP en Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, zip

Compañeros, necesito contar con algún script en bash para poder saber la cantidad de documentos que contiene un archivo ZIP en Linux, estaba realizándolo con `find`, pero no encuentro la combinación para poder ingresar al ZIP y contar su contenido dependiendo de la extensión o no. Por su ayuda de antemano gracias.

Saludos cordiales

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ni puedes ni podrás. `find` **no** soporta eso, solo trabaja con directorios *físicos*.

Tienes varias opciones:

1. Usar un *Sistema de Archivos Virtual*, de los proporcionados por `FUSE`, para *engañar* a `find`. Mas complejo, pero, poder, **se puede**.
2. Usar alguna opción de `unzip` para obtener un listado del contenido del archivo, y contar las líneas resultantes (usando `wc -l`).

Usando este último punto, y usando la opción `-t` (que *testea* el correcto estado de los archivos contenidos), la orden sería:

```
unzip -t ARCHIVO.zip | wc -l
```

> 6

Puesto que `unzip -t` muestra un par de líneas *extra* informativas, el resultado será incorrecto. Añadimos una última operación: restar `2` al resultado:

```
expr `unzip -t ARCHIVO.zip | wc -l` - 2
```

> 4

Comment: Muchas gracias, utilizaré esto y en cuanto tenga un resultado te brindo el feedback

Comment: Perfecta solución, también lo logré a través de:

zipinfo -l ARCHIVO.zip

Aunque esta me lista todos los archivos y al final una línea que me brinda información adicional sobre cantidad de archivos, tamaño sin comprimir, tamaño comprimido, y porcentaje de compresión.

Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Para no tener que descomprimir el archivo puedes utilizar el siguiente comando:

```
zcat file.zip |wc -l
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, pero lo he probado y no devuelve la cantidad correcta. Saludos compañero.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.